# Trigger that will update cells in column of the same value

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, triggers

I am trying to write a macro that will update all cells in a column that have the same value as the adjacent column below are before and after of what I am trying to accomplish. In this example you would update B1 and then any cells in A1 with the same value would update to the B1 value

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Here is the code I am using

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim cel As Range

Set rng1 = Range("A1", Range("A2").End(xlDown))

For Each cel In rng1
    If cel = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value Then
    cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Value
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

I am not sure if what I wrote is correct, but I keep getting out of stack space error, which I think is from the macro continuously looping every time through changing the same cells. I believe this should be possible but I am a little lost.

Comment: Application.enableevents = false. Make sure to set to true before exiting.

Comment: @ScottCraner Does the rest of the code, look accurte for the expected result?

Comment: I would also add a test to ensure that it only fires when column b changes. But otherwise just looking at it it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column <> 2 Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cel In Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If cel = Target.Offset(, -1) Then
            cel.Offset(, 1) = Target
        End If
    Next cel
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid looping if possible. Perhaps use a UDF instead, using the `.Find()` method?

```
Option Explicit

Function myLookup(ByVal rng As Range) As String

    Application.Volatile

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lookupRng As Range, retRng As Range
    Set ws = rng.Parent
    With ws
        Set lookupRng = .Range(.Cells(1, rng.Column), .Cells(rng.Row - 1, rng.Column))
    End With

    Set retRng = lookupRng.Find(rng.Value, ws.Cells(1, rng.Column))
    If retRng Is Nothing Then
        myLookup = vbNullString
    Else
        With retRng
            myLookup = ws.Cells(.Row, .Column + 1)
        End With
    End If

End Function
```

You would place this UDF in the worksheet as follows:

[image]

and fill down. This will prevent circular references because it will search for the cells *above it* only within the `lookupRng`.

And, the final result:

[image]